# Updating Kivy UI during sleep

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, sleep

I am writing a program using Kivy on Raspberry pi. I need to sound a buzzer when a card (rfid) is not accepted and show message on Label.

On first attempt having the sleep inside main function the Label was not updated before the beeps (sleeps) finished. So I put the beeps/sleeps inside a thread but still got same result.
Any help please?

```
            threading.Thread(target=self.beep(3),daemon=True).start()
            self.labelStatus.text = "Card NOT accepted!"
            Clock.schedule_once(self.returntomain,4)
#             BUZZ.on()
#             time.sleep(0.4)
#             BUZZ.off()
#             time.sleep(0.2)
#             BUZZ.on()
#             time.sleep(0.4)
#             BUZZ.off()
#             time.sleep(0.2)
#             BUZZ.on()
#             time.sleep(0.4)
#             BUZZ.off()
```

Comment: threading.Thread(target=self.beep(3),daemon=True).start()  is wrong, if is calling the function within this line.  change to threading.Thread(target=self.beep, args=(3, ), daemon=True).start() at the least.  Threading is a good way to do this.  Another thing that can come up in some circumstances it that your function to update the gui needs to be in main thread so for that gui-updating method put the decorator @mainthread on it.  you get that from here: from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread.  so, your threaded function can call a different function to update gui. the 2nd needs decorator.

Comment: threading.Thread(target=self.beep, args=(3, ), daemon=True).start()                                  Thanks this did the trick. Don't know why the beep function still worked properly in my code but was 'blocking' while now it's not blocking any more and Label is updated instantly.